# AWS Management Console Menu and Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to customize AWS management console so that it shows only the allowed services per user?

Comment: There is no supported way to do this that I'm aware of.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you would like to be able to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS management console is identical for every user.

However, if a user does not have permissions for a particular service, the console may not be able to display some information (eg a list of Amazon S3 buckets or the state of Amazon EC2 instances). Users might also receive error messages explaining that they do not have permission to view some data.

It is not possible to customize the AWS management console.